# Exit Springboot from static function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exit, shutdown

In my Springboot application, I use an "utility" class *(class having only static methods)* in order to validate business rules on my configuration.

E.g.

```
@Component
public class MyClass  {

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(MyConfig config) {
        MyConfigValidator.validate(config);
    }

...
```

If `MyConfigValidator.validate()` finds that something is inconsistent in the configuration, it has to exit the Springboot application

According to my knowledge, the best/only way to exit properly a Springboot applications is to run:

```
    SpringApplication.exit(context, () -> returnCode);
```

`context` being an `ApplicationContext` instance **that must be injected**.

My problem comes with the `static` method `MyConfigValidator.validate()`: being static it can't access to injected values

Let's have a look at `MyConfigValidator`:

```
public class MyConfigValidator {

    public static void validate(MyConfig config) {
        if (!isValid(config)) {
          doExit();
        }
    }

    /// no need to detail here the isValid() method 

   private static void doExit() {
       /// here, I don't know how to get the applicationContext
       SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> returnCode);
   }

}
```

Do you know how could I get the `ApplicationContext` in my `MyConfigValidator` class.
Thank you for your help

Regards,
Philippe

Comment: The only way I can think of is passing the context as a parameter to doExit()

Comment: I'm not sure why your configuration validator is static in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to shutdown the application manually, I would create an [`ApplicationRunner`](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-applicationrunner-and-commandlinerunne) that validates the state on startup of the application. The application will fail to start if an exception is thrown. For instance:

```java
@Component
public class SomeInitializer implements ApplicationRunner {

    private MyConfigValidator configValidator;

    // If it's a Spring bean, inject it
    public SomeInitializer(MyConfigValidator configValidator) {
        this.configValidator = configValidator;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        if (!configValidator.isValid()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Some description");
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to perform validation on configuration properties on startup, you might want to consider using a `@Validated` `@ConfigurationProperties` bean instead:

```java
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="some.prefix")
public class YourProperties {
    @NotEmpty
    private String someProperty;

    // getter and setter
}
```

More info on using validated ConfigurationProperties can be found [here](https://reflectoring.io/validate-spring-boot-configuration-parameters-at-startup/).

Comment: Unfortunately validation using annotations is very limited and (according to my humble knowledge) you can't perform validation business rules such as (foo == false && bar >= 42)

Comment: Custom validations can be added by setting up a ConstraintValidator bean. If you need to perform a validation based on multiple fields (foo == x && bar==y), put the validation on class level instead of field level. [Here](https://memorynotfound.com/custom-password-constraint-validator-annotation/) is an example of a validator that validates whether  a `password` and `confirmPassword` field match, which is similar to your use case.

Comment: If the ConfigurationProperties is too complex, use the ApplicationRunner example instead. Inject properties using `@Value('${someProperty}') String someProperty` and/or autowire the ApplicationContext to access other beans.